# Сколько Н в слове "взволнованы"

Tags: грамотная-речь

В войсках был подъем, все были горды и взволнованы. Утверждаю, что взволнованы-кр.причастие, пишется с Н. Правильно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Сколько Н в слове

См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=54#pp54 :

**§ 102…** **Краткие формы прилагательных**, выражающих различные эмоциональные состояния, могут быть написаны с ***н*** или с ***нн*** в зависимости от передаваемых оттенков значения. Напр.: ***Она взволнована*** (она испытывает волнение)... Возможно и написание ***взволнованна*** (которым подчеркивалось бы, что ее облик выражает волнение)...

Answer (score 3):

При наличии однородного прилагательного лучше писать "взволнованны":

"В войсках был подъем, все были горды и взволнованны".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Слово "взволнованный" может быть причастием и отпричастным прилагательным. Причастие выражает совершенное действие, в этом случае имеется или подразумевается производитель действия: людей волнуют события, море волнует ветер. Прилагательное выражает качественное состояние субъекта.

В полной форме написание одинаковое (НН), а в краткой различное. Она взволнована встречей, море взволновано ветром - Н в кратком причастии. Все оживленны, взволнованны - НН в кратком отпричастном прилагательном.

Иногда это авторское решение.

Если подчеркивается связь с объектом волнения, то это причастие. Если просто описывается состояние, то это прилагательное (часто в этом случае добавляется какое-нибудь однородное прилагательное).

Иногда решение однозначное.

Нельзя сказать: ее лицо взволновано (только НН), так как лицо нельзя взволновать, волнуются только люди и приравненные к ним субъекты. Нужно говорить: государство взволновано (только Н).

ПРИМЕРЫ

И остальные члены экипажа ― второй пилот, штурман, бортмеханик, радист ― были необычно серьезны и явно взволнованны. Бежали Гриша и Соня. Оба были бледны и взволнованны.

Все были взволнованы и подавлены одновременно. Все трое были взволнованы. Провинциальное общество взволновано историей. Воздух, вода, мысли ― все взволновано и смешано, и как тут быть? Лидия встретила Клима оживленно, с радостью, лицо ее было взволновано, уши красные, глаза смеялись.А сердце взволновано уже трепетным и сладким ожиданием.